# How to test values which depends on localization jest, enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, momentjs, enzyme

How to test values that can depend on current localization?

```
function DateNavigation({ locale, date }) {
  return (locale === 'en')
    ? <span>{moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}</span>
    : <span>{moment(date).format('YYYY.MM.DD')}</span>
}
```

This test doesn't work sometimes because of locations

```
it('display date correctly', () => {
    const component = mount(<DateNavigation date={'2022-01-31'} />);

    expect(component.html()).toEqual("<span>31.01.2022</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `moment()`, `moment().format()` functions and its returned value. Test results must be predictable. For the test about `date`, we need to make the test case return a certain value in different systems, time zones and localization.

E.g.

`DateNavigation.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

function DateNavigation({ locale, date }) {
  return locale === 'en' ? (
    <span>{moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}</span>
  ) : (
    <span>{moment(date).format('YYYY.MM.DD')}</span>
  );
}

export default DateNavigation;
```

`DateNavigation.test.jsx`:

```js
import DateNavigation from './DateNavigation';
import moment from 'moment';

jest.mock('moment', () => {
  const mMoment = { format: jest.fn() };
  return jest.fn(() => mMoment);
});

describe('62042433', () => {
  it('display date correctly', () => {
    const date = '31.01.2022';
    moment().format.mockReturnValueOnce(date);
    const component = mount(<DateNavigation date={'2022-01-31'} locale={'en'} />);
    expect(component.html()).toEqual('<span>31.01.2022</span>');
    expect(moment).toBeCalledWith('2022-01-31');
    expect(moment().format).toBeCalledWith('DD.MM.YYYY');
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62042433/DateNavigation.test.jsx (13.544s)
  62042433
    ✓ display date correctly (54ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 DateNavigation.jsx |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6                 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.23s
```